# Use regex to retrive a certian part of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am very new to regex and am trying to learn it but i find it pretty confusing.

My goal is to take a chunk of the string out that will start with some specific characters.

I would like returned everything after `/images`

Example: 
URL: `https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png`

What I would like to return: `/images/srpr/logo4w.png`

Here is my attempt:

```
var src = document.getElementById('image').getAttribute("src"),
    regex = src.match(/images/i);

console.log(regex);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T74L7/10/)

Comment: In this specific case, `substring` works better src.substr(src.lastIndexOf('/images/') + 8)

Comment: Agree with @Vega - in this case, you're much better avoiding regular expressions.  That said, you've already identified that this is just for learning purposes, so carry on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below regex.

```
regex = src.match(/.images.*/i);
console.log(regex[0]);
```

Check this fiddle [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/fc3d9/)

**EDIT**

Actually the dot at the start in the regex would match any character, so you could even replace that with the forward slash for this case. (forward slash is a special char, so escaped with a backward slash)

```
regex = src.match(/\/images.*/i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` too! For something as simple as this, there's really no need to perform a regular expression.

`string = src.split(/images/)[1];`

Will split everything after the '/images/' string in your src.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/T74L7/11/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
var str = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png";
console.log( str.substring( str.indexOf("/images" ) ) );
```

First find the occurrence of "/images" using `indexOf` and grab everything after it using `substring`.

Comment: Thanks! That's a much easier approach for this task but I might as-well mess with regex because I would like to learn it.

Comment: @Shivam - We know you just want to learn, so it's all good.  Many of us have simply developed a _knee-jerk_ reaction to people who try to do things with regex for no reason, so it's hard _not_ to give and/or upvote this advice ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With regex, then this should do:

```
href.match(/^(https|http):\/\/[^\/]*(.*)$/)[2]
```

For learning purpose, I also put here some description as well:

^ : start of string
$ : end of string
(https:http) : this will make regx work with both protocol
:// : this is ://
[^/]* : this is domain
(.*) : this is the remain path

In regex, you put the expression inside `(` and `)` to make it appear in returned value.

Hope this help.